# Android : App is working in Emulator-Tab but it doesn't work in Samsung real Tab

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview

Code provided below is not working in real time device but in emulator it is working:

I don't know the reason why this occurs.

Here is my code:

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String user = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text)).getText().toString();
                if (user.isEmpty()) {
                    user = "World";
                }
                String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Hello "+user+"!';";
                view.loadUrl(javascript);
            }
        });
```

1. Dynamic replace web view content if run emulator it replace webview content but not realtime device
2. If emulator working real time device also working
3. Why it not in real time device?

Comment: Is the CPU architecture of your emulator and tablet same? Your emulator may be using x64 architecture and your tab may be arm.

Comment: why want CPU architecture?Can u explain pls

Comment: Lollipop in emulator and honeycomb in real time

Comment: And what is minSDK in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: minimum SDK 15 in android

Comment: You must need 11 then check it.

Comment: Because honeycomb's api level are 11,12,13.

Comment: ok  i will change

Comment: @Jayapriya Did you get that?

Comment: no same result not working